# How to test fluent-NHibernate's PersistenceSpecification.VerifyTheMappings with lists and relational objects?

Tags: c#, .net, fluent-nhibernate, nunit

How would you test this scenario?

I've just started looking into NHibernate and having my first bash at TDD. So far I've really enjoyed it and have been using fluent-Nhibernate for my mapping of the classes.

However I seem to be hitting a dead end when it comes to using the VerifyTheMappings method on PersistenceSpecification.

Essentially I have two classes, Recipient and RecipientList. The RecipientList class has a mapping to the Recipient with a fluent "HasMany" relationship:

```
public class RecipientListMap : ClassMap<RecipientList>
{

    public RecipientListMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ID);
        Map(x => x.ApplicationID);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.IsDeleted);
        HasMany<Recipient>(x => x.Recipients).WithKeyColumn("RecipientListID").AsList().LazyLoad();
    }

}
```

However when I use the following code in my test:

```
private IList<Recipient> _recipients = new List<Recipient>()
        {
            new Recipient { FirstName = "Joe", LastName = "Bloggs", Email = "joe@bloggs.com", IsDeleted = false },
            new Recipient { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", Email = "john@doe.com", IsDeleted = false },
            new Recipient { FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Smith", Email = "john@smith.com", IsDeleted = false }
        };

        [Test]
        public void Can_Add_RecipientList_To_Database()
        {
            new PersistenceSpecification<RecipientList>(Session)
                .CheckProperty(x => x.Name, "My List")
                .CheckProperty(x => x.Columns, "My columns")
                .CheckProperty(x => x.IsDeleted, false)
                .CheckProperty(x => x.ApplicationID, Guid.NewGuid())
                .CheckProperty(x => x.Recipients, _recipients)
                .VerifyTheMappings();
        }
```

The following error occurs:

```
failed: System.ApplicationException : Expected 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Project.Data.Domains.Recipients.Recipient]' but got 'NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag`1[Project.Data.Domains.Recipients.Recipient]' for Property 'Recipients'
```

I can see that the error is because I am passing in a List and the list returned is a PersistentGenericBag, therefore throwing an error. I don't get how you are suppose test this though if you can't just pass in an IList?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well stupidely I was using the wrong method on PeristenceSpecification.

I should have been using CheckList not CheckProperty.

Duh!

Comment: Be sure not to do the same with CheckReference :)